# Receive json in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to receive this json in android

json:

```
["Coupe","Coupe","Couleurs","Shampoing"]
```

and for read i have this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);

            String str = "";

            str += "id: "+json.getJSONObject(0).getString("Coupe");

            Reponse.setText(str);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And i want to read this json in a spinner.

Help me please!

### ----UPDATE----

For receive Json and read it in a spinner i use this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Spinner s;
List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
String URL;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    s=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.acte);

    URL = "http://trymyjson.com";

    // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread

    new HttpAsyncTask().execute(URL);
    addItemsOnSpinner();

}

public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

    str.add("choix coupe");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, str);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

public static String GET(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // make GET request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

        // receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return result;
}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}

private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return GET(urls[0]);
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
            int len=json.length();
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                str.add(json.get(i).toString());
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And it's work :-)
Thx for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
```

First calculate the length of the array!

```
int len=json.length();
String[] str=new String[len];
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
 {
  str[i]=json.get(i).toString();
 }
```

First add a spinner to your activity

```
Spinner s=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner);
ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,str);
s.setAdapter(adapter);
```